# How to test if dynamic scope have been implemented correctly in lisp?

Tags: lisp, dynamic-scope

I have [simple lisp implementation based on scheme in JavaScript](https://github.com/jcubic/lips). It have lexical scope by default but I've just added dynamic scope as an option. How can I test if I've implemented this correctly:

this code prints 20 and 30:

```
(define (foo x) (* x y))

(define y 1)

(let ((y 2))
   (print (foo 10))
   (let ((y 3))
       (print (foo 10))))
```

so the value y is dynamic because it changes for function foo is there something else that I need to do to make lisp dynamic or this is it?

Is let and function invocation the only places where you can observe dynamic scope?

Comment: `define` is Scheme, not Lisp.

Comment: What determines if a variable is lexically or dynamically scoped?

Comment: @sds it's my lisp implementation and I use define for functions and variables. Lisp is family of languages that use S-Expressions, I can use `get-me-function` to define functions and it still be lisp.

Comment: @coredump if variable is not bound it's taken from scope where is's executed this is dynamic scope, so I thought it's only for functions and let. I'm asking if that's it or is there something else that I need to do to make lisp dynamic?

Comment: "Lisp is family of languages that use S-Expressions" - s-expressions are neither necessary nor sufficient for a language in the wider family of Lisp. See Logo, RLISP, Dylan and others.

Comment: @sds I've updated my question with info that my lisp is based on scheme. I thought it's not important.

Comment: Scheme and some Lisp might different in various ways: for example whether variables and functions are in different namespaces. Common Lisp for example supports dynamic binding for variables, but not for functions.

Comment: Do you have continuations?

Comment: @coredump no continuations and no tail calls.

Comment: Function calls.. `((lambda (y) (print (foo 10))) 2)`, but that is the same as let..

Comment: You probably also want to check things like (assuming `y` is globally not `2`: `((let ((y 2)) (lambda () y)))`, which should not return `2`.  If you have exceptions or other non-local transfers of control you want to check the bindings work properly in their presence.

Answer (score 1):

> *is there something else that I need to do to make lisp dynamic or this is it?*

The fact that `foo` is seeing the binding set up by `y` is an important test case which gives us confidence that some facsimile of dynamic scoping is going on.

Another important test is to show that the dynamic binding **is not captured by a lexical closure**.

Suppose that we bind `y`, and then invoke a function similar to `foo` which instead of just printing a calculation based on `y` captures a lexical closure whose body does that. Then outside of the scope where we bound `y`, we call that returned closure. That closure must no longer see that value of `y` which we had bound. The closure's body referring to `y` must always see the value of `y` in the current dynamic environment.

You might take this for granted, but you'd be surprised how easy it is to get that wrong with some implementations of dynamic scope. If you have some kind of dynamic environment pointer for implementing dynamic scope, and that pointer is somehow embroiled in the lexical closure, oops, you now have closures that capture the dynamic environment. (That, of course, can be a feature: "dynamic closures"). The "called funtions see parent bindings" aspect of dynamic variables works just fine under dynamic closures; it's an independent concern.

As a side note, if your `(define y 1)` is creating a dynamic variable, then how are lexical variables defined? If you want to support both dynamic and lexical scope in the same dialect, you have to have a way of specifying which symbols are going to obey dynamic binding and which will remain lexical.

I.e. since you're supporting dynamic scope "as an option", you need to have a way for it to coexist with the default option of lexical scope, and have tests for that (that you haven't broken lexical scope).

Common Lisp does this by marking the actual symbol special, which is done by `defvar` and `defparameter`.

In Scheme, the `(define ...)` form doesn't do any such thing, and if you make it do that, you break the language; if you want to have CL-like dynamic variables while remaining compatible with Scheme, you need some other form for that like `(define-dynamic y ...)` which will mark the symbol `y` for dynamic binding.

Comment: My dynamic scope option is not per variable like in CL but per interpreter, so I can create dynamic or lexical languages out of single library. And for dynamic one I create two scopes dynamic and lexical. `let` have lexical scope but function call have dynamic binding for unboud variables.